# Value of Eigen::Matrix vanish after loop

Tags: c++, eigen3

I declared `Eigen::Matrix` before execution of loop and used `Eigen::Matrix` variable inside the loop. But value of the predefined variables doesn't change even after the execution of the loop.

```
Eigen::Matrix<double,1,24> Fx,Fy,M;
Fx.setZero(); Fy.setZero(); M.setZero();
for(unsigned int i=0;i<qn.size();i++)
{
    for(unsigned int j=0;j<qn.size();j++)
    {
        double sval=qn[i];
        double tval=qn[j];
        m_shape->update_shapefn(sval,tval);
        Eigen::MatrixXd J = m_shape->get_jacobian();
        double dxds,dxdt,dyds,dydt;
        dxds=J(0,0);dxdt=J(0,1);dyds=J(1,0);dydt=J(1,1);
        Eigen::MatrixXd Bs =get_bsmat_local(i,j);
         Eigen::Matrix<double,1,24> Sx,Sy,Sxy,Tx,Ty,Fx,Fy,M;
         Sx.setZero();Sy.setZero();Sxy.setZero();Tx.setZero();Ty.setZero();

         Sx=Bs.row(1);
         Sy=Bs.row(0);
         Sxy=-1*Bs.row(2);

         Tx=face.nx*Sx+face.ny*Sxy;
         Ty=face.ny*Sy+face.nx*Sxy;

         double Jds= sqrt(dxds*dxds+dyds*dyds);
         double Jdt= sqrt(dxdt*dxdt+dydt*dydt);

         if(face.id==0 )
         {
             Fx.noalias() += qw[i]*qw[j]*Tx*Jds;
             Fy.noalias() += qw[i]*qw[j]*Ty*Jds;
             M.noalias()  +=  qw[i]*qw[j]*(m_shape->X()*Ty-m_shape->Y()*Tx)*Jds;
         }        
    }
}
```

`Fx, Fy, M` are the predefined variables. When I debugged the loop in Qt-creator, I observed that inside the loop, there are variables named `Fx@1, Fy@1, M@1` along with `Fx, Fy and M`. Fx,Fy and M change the values inside the loop but not `Fx@1, Fy@1,M@1`. After the exit of loop, `Fx, Fy and M`revert to the previous state before the loop. What is happening here? Please Help.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: You probably corrupted the heap prior to this

Comment: From your posted function definition for `get_node_ids()` it looks like you're attempting to return `Ids` after the closing braces.

Comment: `CPS4` has no access to `m_nodes` since it's declared private in `CElement`.

Comment: As someone with a problem you can't solve, you are the least qualified to decide what is and is not relevant to the problem. You need to provide a short complete example if you want anything other than a guess. Like, where is `get_node_ids()` called? Are you calling a virtual function from the constructor of a partially constructed object? That's important to know.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, Now I think I've included almost all relevant info. Please tell if anymore is required.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, The function is called from the constructor of another class

Comment: We can't compile and run it, so it's not complete.